# get SINGLE text node from DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, textnode

Need to get all direct nodes from DOM element and don't actually know, how it many and what kind they are.
`.contents()?`
Ok, let's see..

`$('<div />').html('<p>p</p>').contents()` ->
`[<p>​p​</p>​]`

Ok.

`$('<div />').html('textNode').contents()` -> `[]`

WTF?

`$('<div />').html('textNode').append('another').contents()` -> 
`["textNode", "another"]`

Ok, so what about single text node?

Comment: If you use `$('<div />').html('textNode').appendTo('body')` then `.contents()` will have the `textNode`. Seems as jQuery is handling this different as one would expect as long as the structure is not part of the dom.

Comment: As I recognised, my problem based not on jQuery, but on JavaScript.
`q = $('<div></div>').html('dsfdsf')[0]`

`q.childNodes` -> `[]`, but `console.dir(q)` return HTMLDivElement which has one childNode.
Any thoughts about it?

Comment: I work with current HTML structure before appending it to DOM, so `appendTo('body')` not a solution

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as a solution, more as a reference/note. And by the way you're definitely dealing with a jQuery thing here.

Comment: >definitely dealing with a jQuery

`div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('dsf'));
div.childNodes;` -> `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is helpful. A while ago I built a Document Fragment generator using JSON styled input. I also wrote a (somewhat working) reverse function for it so you could turn your  nodeList into a JSON string.

https://gist.github.com/2313580

```
var reverseFunction = function(DOM /* DOM tree or nodeList */) {
    var tree = [];[].forEach.call(DOM, function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Text) {
            tree.push({
                'textContent': obj.textContent
            });
        } else {
            var tmp = {};
            tmp['tagName'] = obj.nodeName;
            for( var data in obj.dataset ) {
                tmp['data-' + data] = obj.dataset[data];
            }
            for (var i = 0, l = obj.attributes.length; i < l; i++) {
                var key = obj.attributes[i].name,
                    val;
                if (key.indexOf('data-') === -1) {
                    switch (key) {
                    case ('class'):
                        key = 'className';
                        break;
                    case ('style'):
                        val = {};
                        obj.attributes[i].value.split(';').forEach(function(rule) {
                            var parts = rule.split(':');
                            val[parts[0]] = parts[1];
                        });
                        break;
                    };
                    tmp[key] = val || obj.attributes[i].value;
                }
            }
            if (obj.childNodes.length > 0) {
                tmp['childNodes'] = reverseFunction(obj.childNodes);
            }
            tree.push(tmp);
        }
    });
    return tree;
};
```

This does find textNodes and separates them... You may be able to extract something from it.

**Update**: to answer a comment in your question above...

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('dsf'));
console.log( div.childNodes.length, div.childNodes, div.childNodes[0].textContent);​
```

I hope this makes a bit more sense to you know. The array appears empty in the console but it is not. check the length and attempt to access it and you will see.

Comment: Your script seems legit. 
`q = $('<div></div>').html('dsfdsf');
w = reverseFunction(q);
w[0].chidlNodes` -> object with single childNode. 
But it would be nice to understand why it is act so strange

Comment: In my last comment to the question there is version without even touching jQuery. And acting the same - if add another appendChild it will return both, but if only one - empty array.

Comment: Yep, it helps. Then i can iterate it through `for`. Thanks.

Comment: element.children() contains text nodes iirc. check caniuse.com for compatibility.

Comment: What's interesting - problem was seen in the Google Chrome, but FF returns single text node normally. So, it's Chrome bug

Comment: yup. there is a reason behind it i'm sure. console.dir( div.childNodes );​ and you'll see everything. read the manpage on .log() https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score -1):

.contents() is concerned with DOM nodes.  That string in the 2nd example is not a DOM element.